# Using Sed to delete multiple lines

Tags: sed, terminal

I have been using

```sh
sed -i '58d' test_file.txt
```

to delete a line &

```sh
sed -i '58,68d' test_file.txt
```

to delete multiple lines in a row

but I tried to use

```sh
sed -i '58;64;93d' test_file.txt
```

to delete those 3 specific lines, which was the answer I found, but I get an error that the

```
;
```

character is an unknown command. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For example you could:

```
sed -i '2d;5d;8d' file
```

test with seq:

```
kent$  seq 10|sed '2d;5d;8d'
1
3
4
6
7
9
10
```

Answer (score 3):

I found

```sh
sed -i  -e 1d -e 3d test_file.txt
```

from the related links as soon as I posted this.